# R-marrangeGrob unique legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, grob

I have a list of 45 ggplot objects that I'm arranging across multiple pages  thanks to the marrangeGrob() function from gridExtra. I would like to show a same and unique legend on each pages.

I know how to extract the legend (g_legend), how to plot my ggplot without the legend. But I do not find a way to have a multipages thanks to marrangeGrob and a unique legend.

I used g_legend() to extract my legend

```
g_legend<-function(a.gplot){
 g <- ggplotGrob(a.gplot + theme(legend.position = "right"))$grobs
 legend <- g[[which(sapply(g, function(x) x$name) == "guide-box")]]
 return(legend)}
```

In order to simplify, the reproductible data set is from diamonds, and let say I want to produce on one page p1 and p2 and on an other page p2 and p1.

```
df <- count(diamonds, cut)

p1 = ggplot(df, aes(x=cut, y=n, label=format(n, big.mark=","), fill=cut)) +
geom_bar(stat="identity") +
geom_text(aes(y=0.5*n), colour="white") +
coord_flip() +
theme(legend.position="bottom")

p2 = ggplot(diamonds %>% sample_n(1000), aes(x=carat, y=price, colour=cut)) +
geom_point()

leg = g_legend(p1)
```

I first try to plot the 4 graphs in one page

```
combined<-arrangeGrob(do.call("arrangeGrob",c(
lapply(list(p1,p2,p2,p1), function(x){ x + theme(legend.position="none")}),ncol=2)),
 leg,
 ncol = 2)
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(combined)
```

which works perfectly but when I try to do it with multipages

```
marrangeGrob(do.call("marrangeGrob",c(lapply(list(p1,p2,p2,p1), function(x){ x + theme(legend.position="none")}),
 ncol=2,nrow=2)),
 leg,
 ncol = 2,nrow=1)
```

I obtained : 
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "wrapvp", value = list(x = 0.5, y = 0.5,  : replacement has 17 rows, data has 5

Does anyone know a way to use marrangeGrob and obtain a unique legend on each multipages?